# SAS EM - Replacing missing interval variable values with user-defined value

Tags: sas, missing-data, enterprise-miner

How do I replacing missing interval variable values with a user-defined value?

I have been through all the options I can see in the `Impute` and `Replacement` nodes, but have not found anything. Google returns a 2003 SAS document that shows how you used to be able to do this with the `Replacement` node, back when there was an imputation column in there.

I'm using the SAS Enterprise Miner OnDemand version 14.1 (the current version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the Impute node. You can find this under the Modify tab in the SEMMA list.

If all else fails, you can always use a SAS code node and the provided EM macro variables to import/export your datasets and modify them as you need.

```
data &em_export_train
     &em_export_validate
     &em_export_test;

    set &em_import_train(in=train)
        &em_import_validate(in=valid)
        &em_import_test(in=test);

    if(missing(var) ) then var = <new value>;

    select;
          when(train) output &em_export_train;
          when(validate) output &em_export_validate;
          when(test) output &em_export_test;
          otherwise;
    end;
run;
```